# How to open port to outside world?

Tags: networking, server, iptables, ufw

I have a remote server with an IP - 111.222.333.444
I want to run an http server on that machine, that runs on localhost:8000

How can I make requests to 111.222.333.444:6000 from outside, from my hope machine, to reach my http-server running on a localhost:8000 on a remote server.

I was using ufw.
Enabled ip_forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf` DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY in `/etc/default/ufw`

Tried this in `/etc/ufw/before.rules`

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
COMMIT
```

In the line `-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000` does the absence of specified ip, where the traffic should come in, sets it to the default IP address of `eth0` interface?

Using Ubuntu-20.04-amd64

If someone could tell, how would he write this thing, to achieve the same purposes. Through editing iptables, or ufw, etc.

**Update:**
Started from the ground up. Http server is running on `localhost:8000`.
My `ufw status` shows this

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
6000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere 
8000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
6000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Added lines into `/etc/ufw/before.rules` before *filter:

```
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
```

What should allow me to type in command line, on a remote server
`curl localhost:6000` or `curl 127.0.0.1:6000` and get the response, as i understand it.
But instead I'm receiving - `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 6000: Connection refused` .

**Update:**
Changed `/etc/ufw/before.rules` from `-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000` to

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
```

Now with the new rules, when i'm making curl request from terminal, it hangs. Instead of producing error.

Comment: You need to know what your Public IP is (the one assigned from your ISP) and you will also need to have port forwarding enabled for port 8000 on your router to your internal IP address.

Comment: @Terrance 111.222.333.444 - It's my public IP (e.g.)
That's my question. How to forward ports? Anything from what I've tried didn't work. 
How to forward port to redirect traffic from public IP to localhost:8000

Comment: It all depends on your router.  Different routers have different settings.  If your server is working internally there is no settings you need to set on your server.

Comment: @Terrance I wasn't clear. Excuse me. Overwhelmed. It's all about remote server. I don't have router. My public IP is provided by VPS hosting, and http-server runs there.

Comment: I would recommend that you fix your question and add details of how you have it hosted and what service it is hosted on.  Others here may have experienced the same thing or have used the same service you do.  Details will really help us help you so that we are not guessing or assuming that you have control of your own server.  Also, add in what version of Ubuntu you are using in your VPS.

Comment: VPSes at providers have separate firewalls sometimes.  Check your vps control panel for firewall or not and if there is a firewall open the port.

Comment: @ThomasWard There are any limitations on provider's side. It's something wrong with what I'm doing.

Comment: @Terrance, yea, thanks for your notes. Added a bit more information. Maybe you can look and it would be obvious, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Depending on what sort of website you’re running, one option would be to simply have Apache listen to both 6000 and 8000. No need for port forwards or proxies 

Comment: If you can, install `nmap` into your VPS and run `nmap -P localhost`.  It should return all open and filtered ports.

Comment: Take a look of Apache Tomcat Server

Answer (score 0):

**Port Forwading**

Using Ngrok might help you if you want to access your localhost from the public internet. [Ngrok](https://ngrok.io) 'exposes your local development server to the Internet', giving you a unique random subdomain url eg. abcdef.ngrok.io to access your localhost from. You can choose a custom domain if you own one [(more info about custom domain is here)](https://ngrok.com/docs/guides/how-to-set-up-a-custom-domain).

**NB**: Unfortunately, you won't have to edit the IP tables with this method.

Comment: Yea, thanks. Still it doesn't reveal the problem. As without reverse proxy server i can't open a port with the server listening

Comment: I don't if these posts might help you - [https://magicesp.com/howto/ubuntu-server-20.04/port-forward-using-iptableses](https://magicesp.com/howto/ubuntu-server-20.04/port-forward-using-iptableses) might help you or [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables)

Comment: yes, thanks a lot. Tried to follow along that one, didn't work out. Still, appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try these commands on the server:

```
$ rm -f /tmp/f ; mkfifo /tmp/f
$ nc -l 6000 </tmp/f | nc localhost 8000 >/tmp/f
```

This will redirect any TCP traffic coming to your server's 6000 port to the TCP port 8000 internally.

Please, note that this will work for a single connection only and the second command above will have to be repeated for each new connection. So, this is not actually a solution, but just a test to see that this is what you actually want to do.